# How to use latex package emaxima in emacs

Tags: latex, maxima

I am trying to use maxima with emaxima package in latex. I am using xubuntu 20.04, emacs 26.3, maxima 5.43.2. Here is my simple latex file.

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[lines]{emaxima}
\begin{document}
  \begin{maxima}
    diff(sin(x^2),x);
  \end{maxima}
\end{document}
```

It compiles giving me a nicely formated maxima cell but does not run maxima on the cell.

I could not find the `emaxima` command to update cell, which according to an old maxima book is:

`C-c C-u c (emaxima-update-cell)`

I also tried inside the cell to change the mode to `maxima-mode` and evaluated the code block, but the maxima interpreter starts in another window, and the solution is displayed there.

I would like it to be included right after the maxima cell. This used to work many years ago, and I have used it. But now does not seem to work. I have the following lines in my `init.el`, but I am not sure if they are relevant.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/maxima/")
(autoload 'maxima-mode "maxima" "Maxima mode" t)
(autoload 'imaxima "imaxima" "Frontend for maxima with Image support" t)
(autoload 'maxima "maxima" "Maxima interaction" t)
(autoload 'imath-mode "imath" "Imath mode for math formula input" t)
(setq imaxima-use-maxima-mode-flag t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ma[cx]" . maxima-mode))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the mode to `emaxima-mode`? You may need to `M-: (require 'emaxima) RET` first. Note that this doesn't work for me as it complains about missing `tex-site` package but you might have that installed (or may be willing to install).

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. I didn't have any problem with tex-site.